# Sum of "DB" and "View" time is sometimes greater than "Completion" time in Rails logs. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, logging, rails-activerecord

After running some performance tests against a local copy of one of my Rails apps, this line appeared in the logs:

```
Completed in 32ms (View: 1, DB: 1143) | 200 OK [http://127.0.0.1/salons/1/calendar/events?staff_id=false&start=1361397600&end=1361484000&_=1361451249651]
```

Here's another:

```
Completed in 133ms (View: 99, DB: 145) | 200 OK [http://127.0.0.1/salons/1/checkins]
```

This makes no sense whatsoever! Do you know what could cause something like this?

By the way, the app is running under Rails 2.3.17 and Ruby 1.9.3.